# Rules of thumbs for writing "queries" using ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I’m currently working on a prototype of a medium size web application, and I thought that it would be good to also experiment with Entity Framework. The problem is that the major part of the application is not the data layer and logic, and so that I don't have much time to play with Entity Framework. On the other hand, the database schema is quite simple.

One of the problems I’m facing is that I cannot find a consistent way to "write queries". As far as I can tell, there are four "interfaces" for the job:

- LINQ to Entities
- LINQ to Entities using LINQ extension methods
- Entity SQL
- Query builder

OK, the first two are essentially the same, but it’s good to use just one for maintenance and consistency.

I’m mostly puzzled by the fact that none of them seems to be complete and the most general. I often find myself cornered and using some ugly looking combination of several of them. My guess is that Entity SQL is the most general one, but writing queries using strings feels like a step back. The main reason I’m experimenting with something like Entity Framework is that I like the compile time checking.

Some other random thought / issues:

- I often also use the ObjectQuery.Include() method, but again it takes a string. Is this  the only way?
- When to use ObjectQuery.Execute() (vs. ToList())? Does it actually execute the query?
- Should execute queries as soon as possible (e.g. using ToList()) or should I not care just let leave the execution for the first enumeration which gets in the way?
- Are ObjectQuery.Skip() and ObjectQuery.Take() available only as extension methods? Is there a better way to do paging? It’s 2009 and almost every web application deals with paging.

Overall, I understand there are many difficulties when implementing an ORM, and often one has to compromise. On the other hand, the direct database access (e.g. ADO.NET) is plain and simple and has well defined interface (tabular results, data readers), so all code - no matter who and when writes it - is consistent. I don’t want to faced with too many choices whenever writing a database query. It’s too tedious and more than likely different developers will come up with different ways.

What are your rules of thumbs?

Comment: "LINQ to Entities using LINQ extension methods": Did you mean LINQ-to-Objects? Since LINQ-to-Entities uses extension methods aswell...

Comment: Interesting question - I've run into similar confusions myself, but this cuts to the heart of the matter: how *should* you use Linq to Entities?  Consistency matters.

Comment: @Yannick: the way I iterprete this is the fact that there are many different ways to do the same thing.  Sure, `BLA.Select(x=>...myProjection...)` is the same as `from x in BLA select ...myProjection...` but using both inconsistently in your code makes things less readable.  For instance, if you're searching through code, it's handy if code doing the same thing looks the same.  To much (pointless) variety is bad practice: you're not adding functionality, you're just steepening the learning curve and making the code less readable.

Comment: @Eamon: Thank you for the clarification. This is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Syntaxwise, possible and probable. And although I agree with the principle of not adding too much variety, LINQ syntax was added to improve readability of complex queries, but some statements are just too simple to write in it. IMO anyone using LINQ should be able to fluently switch between LINQ and method syntax

Comment: The reason I thought you meant LINQ-to-Objects is due to the current limitations of LINQ-to-Entities which sometimes force the user the combine both. The jumping through hoops L2E sometimes requires is a real pain.

Answer (score 2):

I use LINQ-to-Entities as much as possible. I also try and formalise to the lambda-form, as opposed to the extended SQL-style syntax. I have to admit to have had problems enforcing relationships and making compromises on efficiency just to expedite my coding of our application (eg. Master->Child tables may need to be manually loaded) but all in all, EF is a good product.

I do use EF's .Include() method for lazy-loading, which as you say, does require a string input. I find no problem with this, other than that of identifying the string to use which is relatively simple. I guess if you're keen on compile-time checking of such relations, a model similar to: Parent.GetChildren() might be more appropriate.

My application does require some "dynamic" queries to be performed, though. I have two ways of meeting this:

a) I create a mediator object, eg. ClientSearchMediator, which "knows" how to search for clients by name, etc. I can then put this through a SearchHandler.Search(ISearchMediator[] mediators) call (for example). This can be used to target specific data structures and sort results accordingly using LINQ-to-Entities.

b) For a looser experience, possibly as a result of a user designing their own query (using high level tools our application provides), eSQL is ideal for this purpose. It can be made to be injection-safe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough knowledge to address all of this, but I'll at least take a few stabs.

I don't know why you think ADO.NET is more consistent than Entity Framework.  There are many different ways to use ADO.NET and I've definitely seen inconsistency within a single code base.

Entity Framework is currently a 1.0 release and it suffers from many 1.0 type problems (incomplete & inconsistent API, missing features, etc.).

In regards to Include, I assume you are referring to eager loading.  Multiple people (outside of Microsoft) have developed solutions for getting "type safe" includes (try googling something like: Entity Framework ObjectQueryExtension Include).  That said, Include is more of a hint than anything.  You can't force eager loading and you have to always remember to call the IsLoaded() method to see if your request was fulfilled.  As far as I know, the way "Include" works is not changing at all in the next version of Entity Framework (4.0 - to ship with VS 2010).

As far as executing the Linq query as soon as it's built vs. the last possible moment, that decision is situational.  Personally, I would probably execute it as soon as it's built for the most part unless there was a compelling reason not to, but I can see other people going the opposite direction.

There are more mature ORMs on the market and Entity Framework isn't necessarily your best option.  For the most part, you can bend Entity Framework to your will, but you may end up rolling your own implementation of features that come out of the box with other ORMs.

Comment: Which ORM *would* you suggest then?